# 1D array being treated as 2D array in function - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Please tell me if the title is not entirely correct.

I first initialize a pointer to array using malloc in the main, then I pass it to a function which receives a pointer to pointer to int like this:

```
void readfile(int**);

int main(void)
{
  int (*obsF) = malloc(sizeof(int)*16);
  readfile(&obsF);
  free(obsF);
}

void readfile(int **obsF)
{
  //I can do this without errors:
  obsF[0][1] = 1;

}
```

I don't understand why I have to treat it as a 2D array, because if I do `obsF[1] = 1` I get an error. Could someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: Because `obfF[1]` is of type `int*`.

Comment: @GeorgesupportsGoFundMonica could you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: `readfile(int **obsF)` means that `obsF[i]` is of type `int *` so of course you shouldn't assign any `int` values to it. Why did you use `int **` instead of `int *` for `obsF`?

Comment: @kaylum It was actually a mistake now that I am realizing. As Julian Chan told me I should've just passed an int*.It was part of a final project of a college work I've been doing, and I was really stressed because my code wasn't working and suddenly that way did the trick. Now I'm revising it and realized of the mistake and I did not understand this behavior.

Comment: ^^ This does also mean you could use `(*obsF)[1]`. However there doesn't seem to be a reason to use a double pointer in this scenario.

Comment: @GeorgesupportsGoFundMonica definitely not. However from this mistake I could learn a bit more.

Comment: It would be less confusing to use a different name for the function parameter than the argument.  In `readfile`, `obsF` is a pointer to the variable called `obsF` in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function signature from `void readfile(int**)` to `void readfile(int*)` and from `void readfile(int **obsF)` to `void readfile(int *obsF)`.

When you put the function signature as int**, the compiler treats it as a pointer to a pointer, and thus it is treated as a 2D array, and not a 1D array.